# SpringMVC+AspectJ not called

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Hi I read all previous threads on my issue and i applied all suggestions, but i haven't found a solution.

In my springMVC+AspectJ config,  controller works fine but the pointcut is not performed.
Here my configs and code:

```
-- /WEB-INF/web.xml ---
        <web-app>
          <display-name>MODULE-WEB</display-name>

          <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
            </context-param>

           <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
           </listener> 
        ...
```

**

```
-- /WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml -----
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
            xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd"
            >

             <mvc:annotation-driven/>
            <context:annotation-config/>
            <context:component-scan base-package="it.max.test"/>

             <!-- AOP -->
            <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

            <!-- EJB -->    
            <bean id="testService" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:app/MODULE-EJB/TestService"/>
            <property name="businessInterface" value="it.max.test.services.ITestService"/>
            </bean> 

            </beans>
```

**

```
-- Monitor.java ---
package it.max.test.security;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Target(value={ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Monitor {
            }
```

**

```
   -- AuthorizationInterceptor.java --
    package it.max.test.security;

    import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
    import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.CodeSignature;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Aspect
    @Component
    public class AuthorizationInterceptor {

       @Before(value="@within(it.max.test.security.Monitor) || @annotation(it.max.test.security.Monitor)")
        public void before(JoinPoint jp){
            Object[] paramValues=jp.getArgs();
            String[] paramNames=((CodeSignature)jp.getStaticPart().getSignature()).getParameterNames();
            for(int i=0;i<paramValues.length;i++){
                System.out.println("["+paramNames[i]+"]:["+paramValues[i]+"]"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

**

```
--TestController.java---
package it.max.test.controllers;

import it.max.test.security.Monitor;
import it.max.test.services.ITestService;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ITestService testService;

    @Monitor
    @RequestMapping("/test.view")
    protected ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest arg0,HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
        testService.test("AAA");
        mv.setViewName("test");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess you also have a `DispatcherServlet` that is loading the controller class. Aspects (AOP in general) will only be applied to beans in the same context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your annotated method is `protected`, but it should be `public`.

[Spring manual, chapter 9.2.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) says:

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, protected methods are by definition not intercepted, neither for JDK proxies (where this isn’t applicable) nor for CGLIB proxies (where this is technically possible but not recommendable for AOP purposes). As a consequence, any given pointcut will be matched against public methods only!

If you want to match `protected` or `private` methods, use AspectJ via LTW.

Comment: Huawuuu !!!! This was the problem !!!! Methods on the controller must be public. Many thnks guys !!!